# Proof of the mean converges to $0$.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Suppose that $Y$ is a random variable with $E(Y) = 0$ and $Var(Y) = \sigma^2 < \infty$. Let $Z_n$ denote the random variable $Y^2I\{|Y | ≥ \sigma\sqrt{n}\}$. Prove that $E(Z_n) → 0$ as $n → \infty$.

I tried this proof as follows. Since
$$
P(|Y| \geq \sigma \sqrt{n}) = P(Y^2 \geq \sigma^2n) \leq \frac{E[Y^2]}{\sigma^2n} = \frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0\ ,
$$
I have $I\{|Y | ≥ \sigma\sqrt{n}\} \xrightarrow{P} 0$.

Then I defined two events, for any $\epsilon > 0$, $A =\bigg\{Y^2{I\{|Y | ≥ \sigma\sqrt{n}\} < \epsilon} \bigg\}$, $B = \bigg\{ {I\{|Y | ≥ \sigma\sqrt{n}\} < \epsilon}\bigg\}$. Thus $A \subseteq B$. So I conclude that $Z_n = Y^2{I\{|Y | ≥ \sigma\sqrt{n}\}} \xrightarrow{P}0$, which implies $Z_n \xrightarrow{d} 0$. As $Z_n$ is bounded by $Y^2$, $E[Z_n] \rightarrow 0$.

Is there anything wrong with the proof? Are there any better ways to prove this question? I wanted to use the dominated convergence theorem but I couldn't figure out a way.

Comment: I realized that I don't need to define the two events. Since I have proved that $Y^2$ is bounded in probability, then $Y^2 = Op(1)$. So this big Op times the little op (the indicator function converges to 0 in probability) is just another little op.